# How do I return results for one day?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create a sales report where the User can select a daterange and get back a sum of sales and a datetime for each day.

I've made a method that takes two datetimes - StartDate and EndDate and loops objects for all days in between those days so that I can return a Date and a TotalSales = 0 even if no sales has been made that day.

I then join this with my GetOrders-query. This works fine if I have a intervall of dates such as 2017-04-01 - 2017-04-30, but if I send in a startdate and a enddate of the same day, my results come back wrong. Any ideas what Im doing wrong?

Classes:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Discount { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class DailySalesDto
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalSales { get; set; }
}
```

Helper method:

```
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> EachDay(DateTime from, DateTime thru)
    {
        for (var day = from.Date; day.Date <= thru.Date; day = day.AddDays(1))
            yield return day;
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public IEnumerable<DailySalesDto> GetOrders(DateTime startDate, DateTime 
    endDate)
    {
        var DateRange = new List<DailySalesDto>();

        foreach (DateTime day in EachDay(startDate, endDate))
        {
            DailySalesDto newEmpty = new DailySalesDto()
            {
                Date = day,
                TotalSales = 0
            };
            DateRange.Add(newEmpty);
        }

        var salesForPeriod = db.Orders.Where(b => b.OrderDate.Day > startDate.Day && b.OrderDate.Day <= endDate.Day);

        var salesByDay = from s in salesForPeriod
                         group s by s.OrderDate.Day into g
                         select new { Date = g.Key, totalSales = g.Sum(p => p.OrderItems.Select(x => x.Quantity * x.UnitPrice).Sum()) };

        var query = from d in DateRange
                    join s in salesByDay on d.Date.Day equals s.Date into j
                    from s in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new DailySalesDto { Date = d.Date, TotalSales = (s != null) ? s.totalSales : 0m };

        return query.OrderBy(x => x.Date.Day);
    }
```

Results 2017-04-25 - 2017-04-25 (2 orders existing)

/api/SalesVM/?startDate=2017-04-26&endDate=2017-04-26

```
[
  {
    "Date": "2017-04-26T00:00:00",
    "Day": 0,
    "TotalSales": 0
  }
]
```

/api/SalesVM/?startDate=2017-04-25&endDate=2017-04-26

```
[
  {
    "Date": "2017-04-25T00:00:00",
    "Day": 0,
    "TotalSales": 0
  },
  {
    "Date": "2017-04-26T00:00:00",
    "Day": 0,
    "TotalSales": 247
  }
]
```

Comment: For startime, it should be `25-04-2017 00:00:00` and for End time it should be `25-04-2017 23:59:59`. Is that not the case?

Comment: if you put `startDate` and `endDate` of the same day, the means that the time difference is 0. You need to include time to get the results for one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use >= for fetching salesForPeriod start date

```
var salesForPeriod = db.Orders.Where(b => b.OrderDate.Day >= startDate.Day && b.OrderDate.Day <= endDate.Day);
```

Comment: I suppose this will solve your problem. Try to accept as answer

Comment: Gah, I see my mistake now. Works fine, thank you! Will accept as answer in a couple of mins.

Comment: Please do when you can, Thanks